# Efficiently finding a value from one vector in another matlab: error checking if empty

Tags: matlab

I have 3 vectors: `npdf,` `tn(:,1)` and `tn(:,2)` and am finding the values of `npdf` in `tn(:,2)` line by line:

```
    [npdf(1:20,1), tn(1:20,:)]

    ans =

    8.0000    3.0000    1.0000
   11.0000    2.9167    1.0000
    1.0000    3.3000    1.0000
   11.0000    1.2167    1.0000
    5.0000    2.8167    1.0000
    1.0000    2.4000    1.0000
    2.0000    2.4500    1.0000
    4.0000    0.2500    1.0000
   15.0000    3.7500    1.0000
   15.0000    4.9167    1.0000
    1.0000    2.8167    2.0000
   17.0000    0.2500    2.0000
   15.0000    1.0000    3.0000
    4.0000    3.0000    3.0000
    8.0000    0.5833    3.0000
    1.0000    0.5833    3.0000
    3.0000    5.0000    5.0000
   11.0000    3.7500    6.0000
    8.0000    3.0000    7.0000
   15.0000    2.8000    7.0000

for i=1:length(npdf)
  [LOCA,~]=ismember(tn(:,2),npdf(i,1,1));
  dummy=find(LOCA~=0);
  tpdf(i,1)=tn(randi(length(dummy),1,1),1);
end
```

each time it finds the value of `npdf` in `tn(:,2)` it chooses a value from `tn(:,1)`.

Here's the problem: if it can't locate the value from npdf in tn(:,2) then I need to choose the nearest value (in magnitude) in tn(:,2) and proceed. Either that or some sort of interpolation between nearest values.. How would you do this most efficiently?

At your discretion to change the code, it doesn't look very efficient to me.

Comment: On what criteria you are choosing values from `tn(:,1)`. It all looks random to me from this line: `tpdf(i,1)=tn(randi(length(dummy),1,1),1);`. So if you find 5 identical values (i.e. length(dummy)=5), you will choose from first 5 elements of tn(:,1), right?

Comment: @Parag correct. This is because tn(:,1) contains multiple entries which are the same (eg 5 5 5 )corresponding to different tn(:,2) values et(1 2 4 6). But I have no preference for which value I choose in tn(:,1)

Comment: I actually ended up using some linear interpolation if isempty(dummy). Not very smart and results look horrible. Any thoughts?

Comment: I am still confused. Let's take an actual example. In your example, I want to find value from `tn(:,2)` which is closer to the first element of `npdf` i.e. 8. So ideally it should give you `dummy` -> all zeros except last two elements which will be one (since the closest from `tn(:,2)` is 7). Lets say the element indices are 19 and 20. Therefore, you will choose a random number from `1:20` -> lets say you choose 16. Then you will choose the 16th element from `tn(:,1)`. Does this sound right to you?

Comment: Lets say i=1 and I want to find the value npdf(1,1)=8 in tn(:,2), this never occurs however 7 is the nearest value, so I would like to choose this value given that `isempty(dummy)=1` at this point. How do I do that? What comes after I have a handle on.

Comment: Read my word "ideally". Assume that you have done some interpolation, then does that make sense to you, so that I can start thinking in that direction

Comment: @Parag yes this is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done easily by using `knnsearch` as follows:

```
 [idx,D]=knnsearch(tn(:,2),npdf,'K',size(tn,1));
 for i=1:size(D,1)
    tpdf(i,1)=tn(randi(sum(D(i,:)==min(D(i,:))),1,1),1);
 end
```

It finds distance of each value in `npdf` to all the values in `tn`. Then it considers only the nearest value. Then it selects a random indices from `tn(:,1)` as per your code.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you for sticking with my explanations, knnsearch looks very powerful and will come in handy for other things too! :)